# issue with array and json decode

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm a little confused I have the following;

```
array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["result"]=> array(5) { ["account"]=> string(34) "rf2DKsfbZuCa2WwQAg49cRXqYuRCTszUTp" ["assets"]=> array(1) { ["rDroJrYXN7vRzLbH6tFXTViVtXGv5ZJGeZ"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["currency"]=> string(3) "FLX" ["value"]=> string(9) "999999999" } } } ["ledger_hash"]=> string(64) "E44084AAC1F1AE2C7147675BF8F763ED7620DC82E1B1A5BD6DC6F640652F1B63" ["ledger_index"]=> int(17773072) ["validated"]=> bool(true) } ["status"]=> string(7) "success" ["type"]=> string(8) "response" }
```

I am trying to echo the currency;
I have the following but it's not working.

```
  $response = websocket_read($sp,$errstr);
  $decode = json_decode($response, true);
  
    echo'<br><br>';
    echo $decode['result']['assets']['currency'];
    
    echo'<br><br>';
    echo "Server responed with: '" . $response ."'\n";
```

The line that is not working is `echo $decode['result']['assets']['currency'];`

Thankyou

Comment: Assets has an extra key `rDroJrYXN7vRzLbH6tFXTViVtXGv5ZJGeZ` and that one holds an array... To make your life easier, `var_dump($decode)` to get a better insight into the exact structure.

Comment: what am i doing wrong ? `echo $decode['result']['assets']['rDroJrYXN7vRzLbH6tFXTViVtXGv5ZJGeZ']['currency'];`

Comment: `$decode['result']['assets']['rDroJrYXN7vRzLbH6tFXTViVtXGv5ZJGeZ']` is an array of arrays. If you're sure it will always return a single object, then just add a `[0]` after it. Otherwise, you have to iterate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `rDroJrYXN7vRzLbH6tFXTViVtXGv5ZJGeZ` has the value as an array, either remove the square brackets from this part to treat it as value

```
"rDroJrYXN7vRzLbH6tFXTViVtXGv5ZJGeZ":[{"currency":"FLX","value":"999999999"}]
```

to

```
"rDroJrYXN7vRzLbH6tFXTViVtXGv5ZJGeZ":{"currency":"FLX","value":"999999999"}
```

or use index to get the value

```
echo $decode['result']['assets']['rDroJrYXN7vRzLbH6tFXTViVtXGv5ZJGeZ'][0]['currency'];
```